# Want to images load first then title in WordPress loop

Tags: loop

ok I'm creating a portfolio page. I want all the images of the portfolio post stack together. & when visitors hover their mouse in any of the title the image ll show.

for this I've created this loop:

```
<div class="main-interior portfolio" id="portfolio-big-pics" style="display: block;">
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'order' => 'ASC');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php $extraLastClass = $loop->current_post + 1 === $loop->post_count ? ' main-image-porfolio-main' : '';?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail( "thumbnail", array( "class" => "main-image portfolio $extraLastClass" ) ); ?>

            <div class="portfolio-box">

                <h5>Portfolio</h5>
                <ul class="item-list" id="portfolio-list">
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </li>               
                </ul>

            </div>

 <?php endwhile; ?>            
</div>
```

as you can see my images & titles are within the loop. it prints out like: first image & first title, then second image & second title, third image+third title & so go on... what I want is print out all the images first & then the titles. like: first image, second image, third image & then first title, second title, third title. Basically from my code, all the images of the portfolio item ll load first & then the "portfolio-box" div. screenshot attached.
[image]

Comment: hey, i think it would be nice if collect `images title html` in a `variable` and `echo` it after loop

Comment: Or you can run your lopp twice. First time for images and second for titles only.

Comment: @Ravs ok very nice idea.But I'm not good with php, can you tell me how?

Comment: Downvote, I think this questinon is off-topic. Asking for generic PHP/HTML/CSS/JS is off-topic.

Comment: I updated comment, I meant two while loops. I didn't mean running `WP_Query` twice for fetching same data twice. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try it

```
<div class="main-interior portfolio" id="portfolio-big-pics" style="display: block;">
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'order' => 'ASC');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
$img_titles = '';
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $extraLastClass = $loop->current_post + 1 === $loop->post_count ? ' main-image-porfolio-main' : '';
    the_post_thumbnail( "thumbnail", array( "class" => "main-image portfolio $extraLastClass" ) );

    $img_titles .= '<div class="portfolio-box">

                <h5>Portfolio</h5>
                <ul class="item-list" id="portfolio-list">
                <li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>
                </li>               
                </ul>

            </div>';

 endwhile;
 ?>            
</div>
<?php echo $img_titles; ?>
```

Comment: why i got -ve vote?

Comment: i didn't vote it.

Comment: did this solution work for you ?

Comment: in my dreamweaver, it shows the code has an error.

Comment: you can paste your error here

Comment: code updated, try it again

Comment: [http://www.uploadhouse.com/imgs/20416381/]

Comment: code updated, it will work for you, try it again